# Is this space complete or is it incomplete?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, banach-spaces

Show (if possible) that the space of all complex sequences $x=(x_n)$ with only a finite number of terms nonzero (the number of nonzero terms may be different for different members of the space) is complete. We are given a norm $\|x\|=\left(\sum|x_i|^2\right)^{1/2}$.

I have verified that this is a normed vector space since this norm satisfies the four axioms of a normed vector space.

We must show that every Cauchy sequence converges to a point in the space or exhibit a sequence that contradicts the claim.

I was given the following hint, but I'm not sure what to do.

Hint: Consider the sequence $(x_n)$ of sequences $x_n=(1,1/2,1/3,...,1/n,0,0,...)$.

Comment: Here's what I think you should do: First check that the given sequence $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in your space. Second, find a sequence that it converges towards, and note that this sequence is not contained in your space.

Answer (score 1):

First, an easy exercise: show that the sequence is Cauchy.

Now you know that, in order for the space to be complete, that sequence had better converge. If it *does* converge, what would it have to converge to? And is that "point" actually a point in your space?

Comment: I'm a little confused. The sequence is essentially $1\over n$ which is Cauchy and it converges to $\{1,1/2,1/3,...\}$ which isn't in the space since it doesn't contain a finite number of nonzero terms. I feel like this is wrong?

Comment: That's absolutely right! It's Cauchy, but it doesn't converge to any point in the space. So we conclude . . . ?

Comment: That this space with the given norm is not complete. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good hint. One useful idea would be to work in a space that we know is complete and see how it compares. So, observe that the space of all eventually zero complex sequences, call it $X$, is a subspace of $\ell_2$. That $\ell_2$ is complete is standard. See [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space) for some details on sequence spaces. In particular, note that $X$ inherits the norm from $\ell_2$.

Now, only two details need to be checked. First, see that $(1,1/2,1/3,...) \in \ell_2$.

Second, check that $x_n \to (1,1/2,1/3,...)$ in $\ell_2$.

These two facts demonstrate that $X$ is not complete.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x^{(n)}=\left(1,\frac12,\ldots,\frac1n,0,0,\ldots\right)$ for $n=1,2,\ldots$. Then if $n>m$,
$$\left\|x^{(n)}-x^{(m)}\right\| = \left(\sum_{k=m+1}^n |x_k^{(n)}|^2\right)^{\frac12} = \left(\sum_{k=m+1}^n \frac1{k^2}\right)^{\frac12}. $$
Now, as $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}$ is a series with finite terms that converges, we know that $$\sum_{k=m+1}^n \frac1{k^2}\stackrel{n,m\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$$
and hence 
$$\left(\sum_{k=m+1}^n \frac1{k^2}\right)^{\frac12}\stackrel{n,m\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0.$$
Therefore $x^{(n)}$ is a Cauchy sequence, so it has a limit $x$ in the space $$l^2(\mathbb C)=\left\{y^{(n)}\in\mathbb C^{\infty} : \sum_{k=1}^\infty |y_k^{(n)}|^2<\infty\right\}. $$
However, it is clear that 
$$x = \left(1,\frac12,\frac13, \ldots\right), $$
and so $x$ is not in our subspace (as it has an infinite number of nonzero terms). Therefore this subspace is not complete.